# Get File from Main.class.getResource()

Tags: java, file, jar, javasound, getresource

I am making a small game in Java. For this game I just added sounds. So I want to have all my images and audio files in the jar. For pictures this was easy:

```
new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("images/machgd2.png")).getImage()
```

But for audio it only works when I run the program in Eclipse but not from a jar. I use:

```
File soundFile = new File(Main.class.getResource(filename).getFile());
```

So how can I get this file from inside the .jar file?

**Update:**

OK, got it working, thanks to Andrew!
To play the sound I used a class I found on the net, and I found out that class just uses File to get an AudioInputStream, so I dropped the File thing.

Answer (score 5):

When it's in a jar file, it *isn't* a file on the file system, is it? You'll *either* have to copy the file out of the jar file into some temporary location, or use APIs which don't require a file (e.g. ones which only need an `InputStream` or a `URL`, both of which are easily available from jar files using `getResourceAsStream` or `getResource`.).

You haven't shown where you're using `soundFile` - if you show us which APIs you're trying to use, we can try to suggest an appropriate alternative.

Comment: ones which only need an InputStream *or a URL*, since getResource() returns a URL

Comment: @JBNizet: Yes, that was why it was only an 'e.g.' - I didn't want to give too many options. Will edit though, as a URL may well be more useful here...

Answer (score 3):

See **"Playing a `Clip`"** from the [Java Sound info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) here at SO to see..

```
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class LoopSound {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL(
            "http://pscode.org/media/leftright.wav");
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        // getAudioInputStream() also accepts a File or InputStream
        AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.
            getAudioInputStream( url );
        clip.open(ais);
        // loop continuously
        clip.loop(-1);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // A GUI element to prevent the Clip's daemon Thread
                // from terminating at the end of the main()
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Close to exit!");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Which, you might notice, uses an `URL` (as returned by `getResource()`) rather than a `File`.  The method is overloaded to also accept `File` or `InputStream`, but I use the `URL` based version most commonly.